# React components testing. Mocha, Enzyme tests. Errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, jsx

I am using Mocha and Enzyme tests. Write test in React app at first time. Project is large, so I can't do this frm start. Tell me plz, do I need to add something in webpack.config file and what can I do with errors (below) 
 "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" or "Cannot read 'type' of undefined"

[image]

Setup.js code:

```js
require('babel-register')();


var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

var exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    exposedProperties.push(property);
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};

documentRef = document;


process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

function noop() {
  return null;
}

require.extensions['.css'] = noop;
require.extensions['.scss'] = noop;
require.extensions['.md'] = noop;
require.extensions['.png'] = noop;
require.extensions['.svg'] = noop;
require.extensions['.jpg'] = noop;
require.extensions['.jpeg'] = noop;
require.extensions['.gif'] = noop;
```

Test code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import configStore from 'redux-mock-store'

import { defineMessages, FormattedMessage, injectIntl, intlShape } from 'react-intl';

import { LanguageSwitcher } from '../../src/components/LanguageSwitcher';
import { Header } from '../../src/components/Header';
import { SearchBoxRedirect } from '../../src/components/Header';
import { Link } from '../../src/components/Link';
import { Navigation } from '../../src/components/Navigation';


describe('<Header />', () => {
  const mockStore = configStore()

  it('must have an img', () => {
    const intlMockup = {
      formatMessage: () => ('')
    }

    const intlMockupDate = {
      formatDate: () => ('')
    }

    const intlMockupTime = {
      formatTime: () => ('')
    }

    const store = mockStore()


    const wrapper = mount(<Header intl={intlMockup, intlMockupDate, intlMockupTime} />);
    expect(wrapper.find('img')).to.have.length(1);

  });
});
```

Just in case, code of my simple component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { defineMessages, FormattedMessage, injectIntl, intlShape } from 'react-intl';
import SearchBoxRedirect from './SearchBoxRedirect';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import s from './Header.css';
import Link from '../Link';
import Navigation from '../Navigation';
import LanguageSwitcher from '../LanguageSwitcher';
import logoUrl from './logo-small.png';
import logoUrl2x from './logo-small@2x1.png';
import alphaRibbon from './alpha-ribbon.png';

  
export class Header extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    intl: intlShape.isRequired,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.searchbox.refs.queryField.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={s.root}>
        <div className={s.container}>
          <img className={s.alphaRibbon} src={alphaRibbon} alt="alpha" width="50px" />
          <Link className={s.brand} to="/">
            <img src={logoUrl2x} srcSet={`${logoUrl2x} 2x`} width="67" height="38" alt="8kolo" />
            <span className={s.brandTxt}>
              <FormattedMessage {...messages.brand} />
            </span>
          </Link>
          <Navigation className={s.nav} />
          <div className={s.search}>
            <SearchBoxRedirect
              ref={sb => { this.searchbox = sb; }}
              hitsRoute="/"
              searchOnChange
              placeholder={this.props.intl.formatMessage(messages.searchPlaceholder)}
              prefixQueryFields={['full_name']}
            />
          </div>
          {/* <LanguageSwitcher /> */}
        </div>
        {/* <div className={s.banner}>
          <div className={s.container}>
            <FormattedMessage tagName="p" {...messages.bannerDesc} />
          </div>
        </div>*/}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(s)(injectIntl(Header));
```

When I changed `import Header from ../Header` to 'import {Header} from ...' I get a new errors which on screen below 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are testing the HOC that requires the context from the parent component.

You can always export the pure component alongside the default wrapped component for testing.

Component.js

```js
export class Header extends React.Component {
  ...
}
export default withStyles(s)(injectIntl(Header));
```

Test code

```js
import { Header } from '../../src/components/Header';
describe('<Header />', () => {
  it('must have an img', () => {
    const intlMockup = {
      formatMessage: () => (''),
      formatDate: () => (''),
      formatTime: () => (''),
    }
    const store = mockStore()
    const wrapper = mount(<Header intl={intlMockup} store={store} />);
    expect(wrapper.find('img')).to.have.length(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Im sorry, I edited my post with your code and get a new error. Can you look pls?

Comment: @VladTeryoshin, the screenshot attached is so blurring, can you please send me an exact error message? As a side note, I am not sure why you have to use `mount()` instead of `shallow()` method for testing.

Comment: I tried shallow, but got some errors and decided to try mount.

Comment: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

thiis error I have got.

Comment: If I change a component code(update in post) I have an other error: 

  <Header />
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `intl` is marked as required in `Header`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Header
    1) must have an img


  0 passing (229ms)
  1 failing

  1) <Header /> must have an img:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatMessage' of undefined

Comment: The `<Header />` component is wrapped by `injectIntl()`, which injects the `formatMessage()` as a prop. You need to provide a mockup prop to the `<Header />` component.

Comment: Can you explain please how I must do that? Because I imported all files and all components which extends in Header. I update header.test.js file, you can look

Comment: After your code I got 
  <Header />
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `intl.formatDate` is marked as required in `Header`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Header

and 

     Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Link)". Either wrap the root
 component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Link)".

Comment: For `formatDate()` warning, you can add a mockup in a similar way as `formatString()`. To mock up the Redux store, please check the code [here](https://github.com/ming-soon/mern-starter/blob/master/test/unit/app/components/Header/Header.spec.js#L12)

Comment: This situation which now looks better)) But more exceptions and error I have..I do it first time in my life, so I can't understand this now. Thanks a lot. I will be pleasure if you help me again: "  TypeError: this.props.intl.formatMessage is not a function"

Comment: You have to put all mock up functions (`formatDate()`, `formatTime()`) inside the `intlMockup` - at the same level as `formatMessage()`. And pass a `intlMockup` as a prop, not three variables like you do right now.